# Passing id from one page to another in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I want to take id from list.html page and use the same id to display the details on the list-detail.html page.I just started using angularjs.I am not able to display the details based on id. This is my code:
    index.html

```
    <body ng-app="myAppnew">
        <h1>Friends</h1>
        <section ui-view></section>
      </body>
```

list.html

```
<ol>
  <ul ng-repeat="friend in friends">
   <a ui-sref="listDetail({Id: friend.id})">{{friend.name}}</a>
  </ul>
</ol>
```

list-detail.html

```
<h1>Friend Detail</h1>
{{id}}<br />
{{name}}<br />
{{imageLocation}}<br />
```

app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myAppnew', ['ui.router']);
myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
  $stateProvider
    .state('list', {
      url: '/',
      templateUrl: 'list.html',
      controller: 'mainCtrl'
    })
    .state('listDetail', {
      url: '/:Id',
      templateUrl: 'list-detail.html',
      controller: 'mainCtrl'
    });
});

myApp.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams,$http) {
  console.log(arguments);
    $http.get("http://www.fashto.in/rest/getmaincategories").then(function (response) 
                                                           {
         $scope.friends = response.data;
              });


  function findFriend(id){
    var targetFriend = null;
    $scope.friends.forEach(function(friend){
      console.log("Test",friend.id,id,friend.id === id)
      if (friend.id === id) targetFriend = friend;
    }); 
    return targetFriend;
  }


  function list($scope, $stateParams) {
    var friend = findFriend(parseInt($stateParams.Id));

    angular.extend($scope, friend);
  }

  if ($stateParams.Id) {
    list($scope, $stateParams,$http);
    console.log($scope);
  }
});
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are passing dependencies through function parameter which isn't ever needed & don't disobey the law of having DI in picture.

Just remove parameter from `list` & don't pass it while calling that function.

```
function list() {
    var friend = findFriend(parseInt($stateParams.Id));

    angular.extend($scope, friend);
}

if ($stateParams.Id) {
    list();
    console.log($scope);
}
```

---

> **NOTE**: Below description is just to pointing out what was missing in current implementation. No preferring to implement it any sense.

Though the real problem was while calling list function like `list($scope, $stateParams,$http);` you were passing 3 parameters & list function was expecting only two parameters that was mess like `function list($scope, $stateParams) {`, You should either add/remove single parameter from either place.

**Updated/Refactored Code**

```
myApp.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, $http) {
  //creating promise here
  var friendsPromise = $http.get("http://www.fashto.in/rest/getmaincategories").then(function(response) {
    $scope.friends = response.data;
  });


  function findFriend(id) {
    var targetFriend = null;
    //wait till promise resolve
    friendsPromise.then(function() {
      $scope.friends.forEach(function(friend) {
        if (friend.id === id)
          scope.friend = friend; //set current friend.
      });
    });
  }

  function list() {
    findFriend(parseInt($stateParams.Id));
  }

  if ($stateParams.Id) {
    list();
    console.log($scope);
  }
});
```

Then on view do `{{friend}}`/`{{friend.id}}`

Comment: Hello pankaj..i followed your advice but still data is not visible on list-detail page only the {{id}}{{name}}etc are visible in this format  instead of the name or id from the json array...

Comment: @pankaj...i tried the updated code..still no luck..no output is seen on list-details page...it would be kind of you if you send me whole corrected code including changes in other pages too..I might be making some mistake..Thank  You in advance.

Comment: Could you create out plunker of the same? With reproducible issue.

Comment: @Kaushik I asked you to create a working plunkr with demonstartion of your problem statement.. but doesn't seems to be working..

Comment: Files added in plunkr are not running properly ..Ionic app is not running in it...Is there any other way in which I could send you the files? Like rar or zip smthng. .??

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myAppnew', ['ui.router']);
myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
  $stateProvider
    .state('list', {
      url: '/',
      templateUrl: 'list.html',
      controller: 'mainCtrl'
    })
    .state('listDetail', {
      url: '/:Id',
      templateUrl: 'list-detail.html',
      controller: 'mainCtrl'
    });
});

 $scope.viewFriendDetails = function(friend) {
      $state.go('listDetail', {
        Id: friend.id
      });
    };

$scope.getDetails=function() {
$scope.friends.forEach(function(friend){  
      if (friend.id === parseInt($stateParams.Id)) {
        $scope.value=friend;
      } ;
    }); 
}
```

```html
list.html

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="friend in friends" ng-click="viewFriendDetails(friend)">
                {{friend.name}}
  </li>
</ul>

list-detail.html

ng-init="getDetails()"

<ul>
  <li>{{value.name}}</li>
  <li>{{value.id}}</li>
</ul>
```

you have to call getDetails function when the list-detail.html page is loading.i think this will work as you needed.

Comment: @batman..I tried what you suggest but it is not working.Could you please elaborate about what you did and specifically to the list-detail.html page.

Comment: I have sent the id of the friend through the url. I have called a function with friend object as argument and i am getting the id using $stateParams.id.I have called the getDetails() function from list-details.html when the page is loading.